# libc symbols not resolved in perf report

Tags: c++, c, performance, performance-testing, perf

The perf report output is showing hex values for some libc symbols. I have been searched around high and low, still don’t have a clue why some of them are not resolved.

```
-  6%     test         libc-2.12.so                [.] vfprintf                                                                                                                                                        ◆
   - vfprintf                                                                                                                                                                                                     ▒
      - 95.44% _IO_vsnprintf                                                                                                                                                                                      ▒
           30.64% 0                                                                                                                                                                                               ▒
           15.81% 0x7c4548                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
           6.99% 0x536e6f4e746c75                                                                                                                                                                                 ▒
                                                                                                                                                                               ▒
      - 3.83% _IO_vsprintf                                                                                                                                                                                        ▒
           21.05% 0x39393443443838                                                                                                                                                                                ▒
```

System is x86_64 linux box, kernel release 3.2.45. Compiler flag -fno-omit-frame-pointer is added. libc6-dbg package is installed.

As you can see, _IO_vsnprintf and _IO_vsprintf is resolved, but not second level symbols. I don’t know perf or libc well to explain this. Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The second level are probably static functions which do not have names unless your libc has full debugging symbols.

Comment: @R.. Hi R.., could you elaborate on that? i thougt libc6-dbg has full debug symbols, i could be wrong